# Windows Server 2003 forgets folder shares from ISCSI-Volume after restart

Tags: windows-server-2003, iscsi, share

I have running a Server 2003 with the Microsoft ISCSI Initiator. I mapped an ISCSI-Volume and after the restart of the server, the the folders aren't shared anymore. The NTFS-rights are still rigth and the drive letter does not change. Any idea?

Thanks,
cyntaxx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please reference the MS KB regarding this issues:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870964

Basically:

> Make the Server service dependent on
>   the iSCSI Initiator service. For
>   information about how to do this, see
>   the "Make the Server service dependent
>   on the iSCSI Initiator service"
>   section

Comment: And in your iSCSI initiator enable persistent binding if you haven't done so already.