# Share missing after reboot, drive letter was temporarily unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

On Windows Server 2003 x64 I had a drive volume become temporarily unavailable (an external iscsi storage device). In the course of troubleshooting I rebooted the machine, and the external volume did become available again until after the reboot. Now the shares I had pointing to the external volume are no longer available. The registry shows the missing shares and their permissions. How do I get them back?

I would like to avoid recreating them as new shares as it will be some work to apply the various permission levels to each.

This is what *"Computer Management > Shared Folders"* shows now (system shares omitted):

```
Maps   E:\maps
Work   E:\Work
```

and it should be:

```
Maps   E:\Allofit\maps
Work   E:\Allofit\Work
Archives  G:\Archives
Warehouse G:\Warehouse
```

And here are the registry entries for the missing shares (hex values omitted):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\lanmanserver\Shares]
"Archives"=hex(7):43,00,53,00,43,00,46,00,6c,00,61,00,67,00,73,00,3d,00,30,00,00,\
  ...
  00,00
"Warehouse"=hex(7):43,00,53,00,43,00,46,00,6c,00,61,00,67,00,73,00,3d,00,30,00,\
  ...
  00,65,00,3d,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: Here's cure to the problem behind the problem: [Windows Server 2003 forgets folder shares from ISCSI-Volume after restart](http://serverfault.com/questions/45196/windows-server-2003-forgets-folder-shares-from-iscsi-volume-after-restart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was as easy as it is annoying: reboot the server 1 more time, then the old shares are available again.

I speculate that I could have acheived the same result by restarting one or some of the network services, and I considered doing that, but since this is a headless box and all the managment is done from remote was safer to reboot, though I did need to run around and get people to close their active files first.

Answer (score 1):

there's a more simple solution for that: restart the server service.

```
c:\> net stop server
c:\> net start server
```

sometimes other services depend on the lanman server service; they will automatically be restarted in this case.

Comment: Welcome to server fault!  HTML generally gets filtered out; we use markdown instead.  Check out the help link by the search box.  I've edited the correct formatting in for you.